# How to run server written in js with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have installed node.js from here http://nodejs.org/  . in my windows8 machine. copied the example server code in my server.js file

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

then opened the node.js prompt and written node c:/node/server.js 
but nothing happens. 
I am a php developer just trying hands on it, any guidelines will really be helpful.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't need to go in node.js prompt, you just need to use standard command promt and write

```
node c:/node/server.js
```

this also works:

```
node c:\node\server.js
```

and then in your browser:

```
http://localhost:1337
```

Answer (score 9):

Nodejs is a scripting language (like Python or Ruby, and unlike PHP or C++). To run your code, you need to enter a command in the terminal / shell / command prompt. Look for an application shortcut in your operating system by one of those names.

The command to run in the terminal will be

```
node server.js
```

But you will first need to browse in the terminal to the same folder as the file `server.js`. The syntax for using the terminal varies by operating system, look for its documentation.

Comment: or just node server

Comment: PHP too is a scripting language

Comment: While node.js is not a language at all, but an environment to run a javascript engine.

Answer (score 5):

I open a text editor, in my case I used Atom. Paste this code

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

and save as

```
helloworld.js
```

in

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject
```

directory. 
Next I open node.js commamd prompt enter

```
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject
```

next

```
node helloworld.js
```

next I open my chrome browser and I type

```
http://localhost:1337
```

and there it is.

Answer (score 2):

Just go on that directory of your JS file from `cmd` and write `node jsFile.js` or even `node jsFile`; both will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
node server
```

from cmd prompt in that directory

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Linux container, such as on a Chromebook, you will need to manually browse to your localhost's address.  I am aware the newer Chrome OS versions no longer have this problem, but on my Chromebook, I still had to manually browse to the localhost's address for your code to work.

To browse to your locahost's address, type this in command line:
sudo ifconfig

and note the inet address under eth0.

Otherwise, as others have noted, simply type node.js filename and it will work as long as you point the browser to the proper address.

Hope this helps!