# node server.js is not working due to syntax error?

Tags: node.js, git-bash

I am trying to learn node.js and like many others, the first step is like [How to run server written in js with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154357/how-to-run-server-written-in-js-with-node-js)

However, my problem is syntax problem? (as follows)
[image: problemo]

server.js

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a different program called Node.  You may want to uninstall it, then install actual Node from here:https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: i used which node, turned out its from /c/Program Files/Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 R2/Bin/node, not convinced if i should uninstall it I downloaded the binary and put it in the working folder, its working now, thanks!