# Getting error while creating server fir display wifi scanning result in browser

Tags: javascript

i am writing a code for display the scan result on web server via http but is always gives me errr any one can solve this issue here is my code

```
var http = require('http');    
var wifi = require('node-wifi');

wifi.init({    
    debug : true,    
    iface: 'wlan0'    
});     

http.createServer(function (req, res) {    
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});    
    var otherArray = ["item1", "item2"];    
    var otherObject = { item1: "item1val", item2: "item2val" };    
    var json = JSON.stringify({     
       anObject: otherObject,     
       anArray: otherArray,     
       another: "item"    
      });    
    wifi.scan(function(networks){    
        console.log(networks);    
    });    
    res.end(json,networks);    
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');    
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: Please add the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why I'am answering, cause I think your code is completely copied from these posts:

- [How to run server written in js with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154357/how-to-run-server-written-in-js-with-node-js)
- [Responding with a JSON object in NodeJS (converting object/array to JSON string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892569/responding-with-a-json-object-in-nodejs-converting-object-array-to-json-string)

But here you go. Try this:

```js
var http = require('http');
var wifi = require('node-wifi');

wifi.init({
    debug : true,
    iface: 'wlan0'
});

// listen on port 1337
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    // set response header
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    // scan for wifi networks
    wifi.scan((err, networks) => {
        // check if there is an error
        if (err) {
            res.end(`{"error":"${err}"}`);
        } 
        // stringify your network object and give it back to the client
        else {
            res.end(JSON.stringify(networks));
        }
    });
}).listen(1337);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

You can also type this into your cli:

- Get all network devices: `arp -a`
- Filter network devices: `arp -a | grep en0`

Comment: It works bro now i just want to how i can use this file in my Ionic framework

Comment: This is an other question. stackoverflow is not a place to let people write code for you. If this is the correct answer, mark it. Anyway ... You have to do an AJAX-Call to `http://127.0.0.1:1337/` with the help of angular `$http`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http